# CRF++-0.58 installation on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition, crf

getting error: "error while loading shared libraries: libcrfpp.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 3):

run `sudo ldconfig`
and then try again in a new terminal window.
I hope it should solve your problem.

Also you can see the installation procedure in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b3DmE2jYzg

Hope it helps

Comment: I agree, the directions on the website are missing the `ldconfig` line after `make install`.

Answer (score 0):

Error means that shared library was not installed correctly. Could you please mention the steps you followed before you got this error.

Also see installation steps give here: https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/#install

Comment: I got rid of above error by adding  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib  in .bashrc file but now getting  error while loading shared libraries: libcrfpp.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64  so could you please tell me reason for the same.